# Is there a more Django way to convert underscore string into Django model?

Tags: python, django

I wrote my own helper function that will convert a underscore string and return the Django model

Django version 1.11

```
from django.apps import apps

def _underscore_string_to_model(in_str, app_name, delim="_"):
    chunks = in_str.split(delim)
    chunks[0:] = [_.title() for _ in chunks[0:]]
    return apps.get_model(app_name, "".join(chunks))
```

Is there an existing function or library that already does this? I have been looking around but there appears to be none hence i wrote my own. I am happy to keep using this but prefer to re-use existing if possible

UPDATE

THis is how I use it in one of the views.py

```
model = _underscore_string_to_model('some_model', 'some_app')
```

I will then use `model._meta.get_fields()` and perform further operations on the fields to get those that are concrete and nonauto. All these will be inside another function called `_do_something`

Furthermore I will then assign the fields into a view variable called `some_model_fields`

And I am doing this for multiple models

Hence I wanted to be more DRY in my code rather than type out the same operations again and again for the 5-6 models

I will end up typing

```
model = _do_something(underscore_string, app)
```

several times, but that's still less verbose than typing the same operations multiple times

Comment: I'm not sure what `in_str` contains - could you give us an example?

Comment: What is an "underscore string", where is it coming from, and why are you using it?

Comment: I may be missing something, but why can't you just use `apps.get_model('appname', 'modelname')` directly in `_do_something()`? If you're getting names with underscores in them from somewhere and you don't have control of that, you can convert them to the model name that Django expects with `underscore_name.replace('_', '')`; they don't need to be camel-cased.

Comment: Oh I thought django requires title case to get the model object

Comment: Accoring to [the `get_model` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model), model names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks @Blurp. yes I see this is a better way. U want to write into answer, so I can give you the green tick?